# Why doesn't this simple javascript replace change the dash to slash?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML element:

```
<div id='4-12-2012' class='date'>blah blah blah</div>
```

And I'm binding a click event to .date, so when it's clicked, a function is called. My goal is to end up with the date (from the ID) with slashes instead of dashes:

```
d = $(this).attr('id').replace('/-/g', '/');
alert(d);
```

This can't be much more straightforward... but the result that is displayed with the alert() still has dashes, "4-12-2012"... what totally obvious thing am I missing here?! :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer to your question has already been posted, but on a side note, I see no reason to use jquery in this situation. All it is doing is calling un-needed functions

try this

```
d = this.id.replace(/-/g, '/');
```

here is a good reference with testing:

http://jsperf.com/el-attr-id-vs-el-id/7

edit: forgot to remove the ticks

Comment: Thanks- right answer on the regexp and good catch that I didn't need to use jQuery here, too.

Answer (score 5):

try this :

remove the `'` around the regex

```
d = $(this).attr('id').replace(/-/g, '/');
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple regexp, [as seen on this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NECJB/3/):

```
d = $(this).attr('id').replace(/-/g, '/')
```

Comment: This only seems to change the first dash and changes it to nothing, not a slash.

Answer (score 2):

Don't put the regex in quotes:

```
d = $(this).attr('id').replace(/-/g, '/');
```

Comment: Actually, Konerak is wrong: without the regexp, it will only replace the first occurence ;]